# Resolves propagating up multiple calling async functions

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, ecmascript-2016

I've been trying to get the `reject`s of my asynchronous functions to bubble back up to their callers, but it's not working for some reason. Here's some tested example code:

```
"use strict";

class Test {
   constructor() {
      this.do1();
   }

   async do1() {
      try { this.do2(); } catch(reason) { console.error(reason); }
   }

   async do2() {
      for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         await this.do3();
         console.log(`completed ${i}`);
      }
      console.log("finished do1");
   }

   async do3() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         setTimeout(() => {
            if(Math.random() < 0.3) reject('###rejected');
            else resolve("###success");
         }, 1000);
      });
   }
}

export default Test;
```

Chrome just gives me this every time: `Unhandled promise rejection ###rejected`.

Any idea why this is happening? I'd like to be able to handle all thrown errors from a higher level than `do2()` (the above example works fine if the try/catch is in `do2()` and wraps `await this.do3();`). Thanks!

**Edit:** To be a bit more explicit, if I take the try/catch out of `do1()` and put it in `do2()` as follows, everything works fine:

```
async do2() {
   try {
      for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         await this.do3();
         console.log(`completed ${i}`);
      }
      console.log("finished do1");
   } catch(reason) { console.error(reason); }
}
```

Comment: How about placing `await` before `this.do2();`?

Comment: Silly me! Thanks so much. I've accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async do1() {
    try {
        await this.do2();
    }
    catch(reason) {
        console.error(reason);
    }
}
```

`do2` is an asynchronous function. And you call it without `await`. So, when it completes there's no try-catch clauses around it.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/944911) and [this article](http://ruben.verborgh.org/blog/2012/12/31/asynchronous-error-handling-in-javascript/) for more details.